# Gridview Adapter inside ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview, gridview, baseadapter

I have a `ListView` with a `gridview` for each item:

[image]

So when I press the add button I need to add a new item to the `gridView`(`scenesGridViewAdapter`) adapter, but when I press the add button always is added to the last gridview.

```
public class ScenesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<SceneObject> sceneObjects;
    private ArrayList<ScenesGridViewAdapter> scenesGridViewAdapters;
    private ScenesGridViewAdapter scenesGridViewAdapter;

    public ScenesAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<SceneObject> sceneObjects) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.sceneObjects = sceneObjects;
        this.scenesGridViewAdapters = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.sceneObjects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_scenes_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvStepIndex = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_scene_index);
            viewHolder.bmb1 = (BoomMenuButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bmb_open_item_menu);
            viewHolder.scenesGridView = (ScenesGridView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.gv_scene_items) ;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        int index = position + 1;

        viewHolder.tvStepIndex.setText("" + index);

        scenesGridViewAdapter = new
                ScenesGridViewAdapter(this.activity, sceneObjects.get(position).getScenes());

        viewHolder.scenesGridView.setAdapter(scenesGridViewAdapter);

        viewHolder.bmb1.clearBuilders();

        viewHolder.bmb1.addBuilder(BuilderManager.getTextOutsideCircleButtonBuilder("Añadir acción"));
        viewHolder.bmb1.addBuilder(BuilderManager.getTextOutsideCircleButtonBuilder("Eliminar paso"));

        viewHolder.bmb1.setOnBoomListener(new OnBoomListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClicked(int index, BoomButton boomButton) {
                switch (index){
                    case 0:
                        scenesGridViewAdapter.addNew("hello");
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        sceneObjects.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onBackgroundClick() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBoomWillHide() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBoomDidHide() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBoomWillShow() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBoomDidShow() {

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvStepIndex;
        ScenesGridView scenesGridView;
        BoomMenuButton bmb1;
    }

    public void addNewScene(SceneObject sceneObject){
        sceneObjects.add(sceneObject);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to add and item to the `gridview` position?

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a good practice. Instead of listView use _RecyclerView_.

Comment: Yes I know is a bad practice put a scrollview inside a scrollview but i dont know how to do it with other way...

Comment: If you dig a google you can find it.

Comment: I did but I cant find how to get a view like that...